# Object not found, but does exist

Tags: django, django-models

I have an existing working site, that takes advantage of Adobe Lightroom's catalog being an sqlite3 db. The model is auto-generated.

Whilst updating the code for the site (to TemplateView and streamlining), I thought I'd get adventurous and pull on one of the class models to get the information about how many times a face (person) appears in the photos.

The model:

```
class Aglibrarykeywordpopularity(models.Model):
    id_local = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    occurrences = models.TextField()  # This field type is a guess.
    popularity = models.TextField()  # This field type is a guess.
    tag = models.TextField(unique=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'AgLibraryKeywordPopularity'
```

The 'tag' value is obtainable from another model, where it's called 'id_local':

```
face_id = list(Aglibrarykeyword.objects.values_list('id_local', flat=True))
```

The values for the 'face_id' are all present in the previous 'tag' field when you view the db.
However, when using:

```
for a in face_id:
        face_pop.append(Aglibrarykeywordpopularity.objects.get(tag=a).occurrences)
```

.. it complains that there are no matches. I've substituted `a` for a number, or string of the number, even adding `.0` to the representation, and it still complains no matches. I've tried `.filter...first()` etc.

```
slides.models.DoesNotExist: Aglibrarykeywordpopularity matching query does not exist
```

My current work-around is going to output All() of the objects to lists and obtain the values I want that way - which works, but I'm interested more in why it's not working as it should.

Something I notice is that the model has `tag` defined as `TextField`, and when I obtain the values myself from `All()` they are float numbers. Is it the case that there's a sort of 3 way mismatching of variable types, 1)the model 2)the data 3)the query - so no matter if I put a float number or text in my query, it will never match? i.e. do I have to change the model, migrate it and all should be well? (as I'm no Django expert, does the `"managed = False"` mean that even if I do this, it will not effect the db data?)

TIA for comments.

Comment: Did you forget `popularity` in this line: `face_id = list(Aglibrarykeyword.objects ...`

Comment: Nah, there's no need for `popularity` to be in the Query. The problem appeared to be as I noticed. I changed `tag` in the model from `TextField` to `IntegerField` (even tho for some reason Adobe have stored it as a `float`) and the Query now works.